# python re.findall returns a list of tuples (strings are expected)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

re.findall returns a list of tuples that containing the expected strings and also something unexpected.

I was conducting a function `findtags(text)` to find `tags` in a given paragraph `text`. When I called `re.findall(tags, text)` to find defined tags in the text, it returns a list of tuple. Each tuple in the list contains the string that I expected it to return.

The function `findtags(text)` is as follows:

```
import re

def findtags(text):
    parms = '(\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*)*'
    tags = '(<\s*\w+\s*' + parms + '\s*/?>)'
    print(re.findall(tags, text))
    return re.findall(tags, text)

testtext1 = """
My favorite website in the world is probably 
<a href="www.udacity.com">Udacity</a>. If you want 
that link to open in a <b>new tab</b> by default, you should
write <a href="www.udacity.com"target="_blank">Udacity</a>
instead!
"""

findtags(testtext1)
```

The expected result is

```
['<a href="www.udacity.com">', 
 '<b>', 
 '<a href="www.udacity.com"target="_blank">']
```

The actual result is

```
[('<a href="www.udacity.com">', 'href="www.udacity.com"'), 
 ('<b>', ''), 
 ('<a href="www.udacity.com"target="_blank">', 'target="_blank"')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` return a tuple because you have two capturing group just make the `params` group non capturing one using `?:`:

```
import re

def findtags(text):
    # make this non capturing group
    parms = '(?:\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*)*'
    tags = '(<\s*\w+\s*' + parms + '\s*/?>)'
    print(re.findall(tags, text))
    return re.findall(tags, text)

testtext1 = """
My favorite website in the world is probably 
<a href="www.udacity.com">Udacity</a>. If you want 
that link to open in a <b>new tab</b> by default, you should
write <a href="www.udacity.com"target="_blank">Udacity</a>
instead!
"""

findtags(testtext1)
```

OUPUT:

```
['<a href="www.udacity.com">', '<b>', '<a href="www.udacity.com"target="_blank">']
```

Another why is if there is no capturing group `re.findall` will return matched text:

```
# non capturing group
parms = '(?:\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*)*'
# no group at all
tags = '<\s*\w+\s*' + parms + '\s*/?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs for `re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, *return a list of groups*; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

In your case, the stuff in parentheses in `parms = '(\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*)*'` is a repeated group, so a list of tuples of possibly empty strings is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't want to return your inner capture group matches, so make it a non-capturing group instead.

```
parms = '(?:\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*)*'
```